# display block não está funcionando no jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho o seguinte `jQuery` **script**:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "_scripts/_php/_validacoes/cadastrarCelulaMembro.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {   
             idPastor : $("#idPastor").val(),
             idRede : $("#idRede").val(),
             idRegiao : $("#idRegiao").val(),
             idArea : $("#idArea").val(),
             idSetor : $("#idSetor").val(),
             idCelula : $("#idCelula").val(),
             idMembro : $("#idMembro").val()
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#buttonCadastrarCelulaMembro").attr('display','none');
            $("#imgCarregando").attr('display','block');
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#buttonCadastrarCelulaMembro").attr('display','block');
            $("#imgCarregando").attr('display','none');
            if (result[0] == "Erro")
                $(".resposta").html(result[1]);
            else
                $(".resposta").html(result[1]);
        }
    });
  }
```

A ideia é ao entrar no `$.ajax` e antes de enviar o **form**, dar um `display: none` no **button** e um `display: block` em uma **imagem** de *loader*

```
beforeSend: function() {
    $("#buttonCadastrarCelulaMembro").attr('display','none');
    $("#imgCarregando").attr('display','block');
},
```

E, depois de receber o retorno do **PHP**, fazer o processo inverso.

```
success: function (result) {
                $("#buttonCadastrarCelulaMembro").attr('display','block');
                $("#imgCarregando").attr('display','none');
...
```

Mas não está ocorrendo isso.

Onde estou errando?

Eis o final do formulário:

```
...

    <button id="buttonCadastrarCelulaMembro" class="button">Cadastrar Membro na Célula</button>
    <img id="imgCarregando" style="display: none" src="_imgs/carregando.gif" />
    <br />
<div class="resposta"></div>
</div> 
<div class="dadosMembro"></div>
```

Classe buuton CSS

```
.button {
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Troque `attr` por `css`. Ficando assim:

```
$("#buttonCadastrarCelulaMembro").css('display','none');
$("#imgCarregando").css('display','block');
```

Comment: Esqueci que css não é atributo e sim estilo.

No caso, tem que ser 
  
.css() 

e não 

.actribute() 

ou 

.prop().

Answer (score -1):

Esqueci que `css` não é **atributo** e sim **estilo**.

No caso, tem que ser

```
.css()
```

e não

```
.actribute()
```

ou

```
.prop()
```